# Browser communication with Unity3d web player

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I need to set the value of a static member in unity from my browser using javascript:

In Unity3D, I have the following script file:

ScriptName: Glob.js

```
static var myValue;

function setValue() {
Glob.myValue=15;
}
```

In my browser, I'm trying to call the function setValue as follow:

```
//u is the unity object:

u.getUnity().SendMessage("Glob", "setValue", "");
```

the javascript function doesnt give error, but the value myValue or the function setValue is not getting called, how can I change a global static member with JavaScript?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not returning the value of the setValue function. I think the following code could work:

```
static var myValue;

function setValue() {
    Glob.myValue = 15;
    return Glob.myValue;
}
```

and

```
var myValueInUnity = u.getUnity().SendMessage("Glob", "setValue", "");
console.log(myValueInUnity);
```

Comment: Thanks @osi, it doesn't work, actually I don't need the returned value, I just want to call the function setValue to set the internal value of the game, however with your code, console.log shows undefined, thanks